# Rewrite base domain to index.php

Tags: .htaccess, redirect, mod-rewrite, indexing, url-rewriting

I'm trying to create a dynamic system on my PHP project and this is what my .htaccess looks like:

```
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
    RewriteEngine On
    RewriteBase /

    RewriteRule ^pages/?$ resources/pages/page.php [NC,L]
    RewriteRule ^([A-Za-z0-9-]+)?$ resources/pages/post-or-category.php?tcs=$1 [NC,L]   
</IfModule>
```

/pages/ and dynamic post or category page works but the second rule redirects all if the above doesn't redirect. Since it's a PHP script for getting posts and categories, I don't want to make index check on that. Is there a way to rewrite if there is nothing on the domain (ex: `www.domain.com` or `domain.com`).

Also, I distinguish posts and categories in the script with the last world on URL (ex: P435345 for posts, C935943 for categories [numbers are id's]). Is it possible to check if URL's last word starts with P or C in .htaccess to redirect other URL's to 404?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use directives `RewriteCond` before `RewriteRule` as this will not redirect if any file or directory exists. For eg. It will not redirect `domain.com/index.php` to `resources/pages/post-or-category.php`

```
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
```

Comment: Thanks! I added this on top of "any" rule and it worked. Is there a rewrite condition to block specific requests for files like 'resources/config.php'?

Comment: @ErenKara You can use`RewriteRule ^resources/config.php$ - [R=403,P]`. `R=403` for forbidden.

Comment: when I use this "RewriteRule    ^resources/config.php    [R=403, NC, L]" I get Error 500 on every page. Also, I still need to access config.php from other files. Does this block access from other PHP files as well?

Comment: You missed some information `-`. Anyway, if want to block it from PHP then you can use `header` function to redirect or you can set required permission which allows you to include the file inside another PHP file.